# Enabling OAuth2 with Feign for scheduled cross-service tasks

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to solve a puzzle with enabling OAuth2-based authentication for my Feign client that is used for cross-service communication.

In normal cases, when a user pushes a request through API, I'm able to take all authentication details needed from the Spring's `SecurityContextHolder` (as it normally does its job and fills all the details objects) and enhance Feign's `Request` as follows:

```
public class FeignAccessTokenRelyInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FeignAccessTokenRelyInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            String tokenValue = null;
            if (auth.getDetails() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
                OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
                tokenValue = details.getTokenValue();
            }
            if (tokenValue == null) {
                log.warn("Current token value is null");
                return;
            }
            template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenValue);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when it comes to scheduled calls that are triggered inside the system, the `SecurityContext` is obviously empty. I'm filling it with `UserInfoTokenServices` by manually requesting the access token by client credentials flow beforehand and loading user details:

```
OAuth2Authentication authentication = userInfoTokenServices.loadAuthentication(accessToken);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But such construction doesn't fill `OAuth2Authentication.details`, on which I rely to get an access token. I tried extending `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails`, but the only constructor requires `HttpServletRequest` which is hard to get inside a scheduled task, and making a dummy instance of it feels like a bad choice.

So far, I see the only adequate option to make a separate custom implementation of details holder and pass it to `OAuth2Authentication` along with the access token I have. And then pick it up in `FeignAccessTokenRelyInterceptor`.

**The question**

Maybe there are some other options where I can store my access token in the security context and reliably get it from there, in order not to produce new custom classes?

Will be glad for any help.

Some related links I've studied:

- [How to get custom user info from OAuth2 authorization server /user endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056169/how-to-get-custom-user-info-from-oauth2-authorization-server-user-endpoint)
- [Spring Boot / Spring Cloud / Spring Security: How to correctly obtain an OAuth2 Access Token in a scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526361/spring-boot-spring-cloud-spring-security-how-to-correctly-obtain-an-oauth2)
- [Spring @FeignClient , OAuth2 and @Scheduled not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297496/spring-feignclient-oauth2-and-scheduled-not-working)
- [How can I authenticate a system user for scheduled processes in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684505/how-can-i-authenticate-a-system-user-for-scheduled-processes-in-spring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the history, hope that'd help someone like me struggling with that.

I didn't find a better way than the initial one and made a custom `InternalOAuth2Details` to hold a token value obtained from Spring's OAuth services. Then, in the `FeignAccessTokenRelyInterceptor` I simply check if current details are `InternalOAuth2Details` and try to get a token value from it, as follows:

```
@Override
public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (auth != null){
        String tokenValue = null;
        if (auth.getDetails() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
            tokenValue = details.getTokenValue();
        } else if (auth.getDetails() instanceof InternalOAuth2Details) {
            InternalOAuth2Details details = (InternalOAuth2Details) auth.getDetails();
            tokenValue = details.getTokenValue();
        }
        if (tokenValue == null) {
            log.warn("Current token value is null");
            return;
        }
        template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenValue);
    }
}
```

I bet it isn't the best solution, but it seems to work quite stable as of now.

Answer (score 0):

InternalOAuth2Details out of date

Comment: Could you elaborate? How does this answer the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).